# How do I add two curve25519 points

Tags: go, cryptography, curve-25519

I have two points ([32]byte) on curve25519. How do I add them (a + b). I obviously can't do it using big.Int, since they aren't numbers but points on the curve. I haven't found so far any library to do something similar to what I can do using [edwards25519](https://github.com/FiloSottile/edwards25519/tree/c5477978affeeac681d1e732d1655e934625b479):

```golang
a := [32]byte // I get that from another function
b := [32]byte // also from another function
pointA, _ := new(edwards25519.Point).SetBytes(a)
pointB, _ := new(edwards25519.Point).SetBytes(b)
pointC := pointA.Add(pointA, pointB)

fmt.Println(pointC.Bytes())
```

I already tried using this and converting the result to the montgomery curve using `&edwards25519.Point{}.BytesMontgomery()`, but I was not able to import neither `a` nor `b` into the edwards25519 curve, since they are points on the curve25519.

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: Adding two points is part of an algorithm i am currently implementing

Comment: What is the algorithm? ECDH?

Comment: Sort of, but not really. I am currently working on implementing the client protocol of teamspeak 3. The key exchange contains parsing multiple blocks of the license and adding the resulting points on the curve. This is afaik not really standard in any way of doing that, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `libsodium` to achieve this with two steps.

1. Start with `Edwards25519/Ed25519` keys, generate two public keys/points, then call `crypto_core_ed25519_add` ([documentation](https://doc.libsodium.org/advanced/point-arithmetic)).
2. Covert the resultant to `curve25519` using `crypto_sign_ed25519_pk_to_curve25519` via birational map ([documentation](https://doc.libsodium.org/advanced/ed25519-curve25519)).

There are bindings for `Go`. You need to be careful and not use some "random" lib, this stuff is hard to get right and hard to do in constant time (avoid side channels).

[RFC 7748](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7748#page-5) provides the formulas to map `(x, y) Ed25519 Edwards` points to `(u, v) Curve25519 Montgomery` points and vice versa.

The birational maps are:

```
 (u, v) = ((1+y)/(1-y), sqrt(-486664)*u/x)
 (x, y) = (sqrt(-486664)*u/v, (u-1)/(u+1))
```

Comment: but how can I convert a curve25519 point to a ed25519 point? I can't just generate a new key, since I get them from the server. You can read what I am trying to do [here](https://github.com/ReSpeak/tsdeclarations/blob/master/ts3protocol.md#3224-calculating-the-shared-secret)

Comment: @PhilippSchöppner updated answer with solution

Comment: While reading your answer an article comes to my mind that was published around 2003 in which the researcher finds the x coordinate from the Montgomery Ladder. If I've found it, will notify you.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help thus far! However, I have not been able to implement it. I am not at all familiar with cryptography and the math behind it. I have been trying to understand at least some of it and I get most of it. My biggest problem doesn't even lie in the maths but how I get from the result of `"golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519".X25519([]byte, []byte)` to a (u, v) point? I have looked at the [source](https://github.com/golang/crypto/tree/master/curve25519) and didn't understand anything it is doing. Can you provide some inside into this for me @Woodstock ?